# Mortality probability

Tags: probability

It is given: $$μ_{80.5}=0.0202,$$ $$μ_{81.5}=0.0408, $$ $$μ_{82.5}=0.0619.$$

Find $_2p_{80.5}$. Use Uniform Distribution of Death (**UDD**) aproximation for Fractional Age.

**I started from:**

According to UDD formula $μ_{x+t} = \frac{q_{x}}{1-tq_{x}} $, I found $q_{80} = 0.019, q_{81}=0.039, q_{82}=0.06$.

It is known that $q_{x}+p_{x}=1$, so $p_{80}=1-q_{80}=1-0.019=0.981.$ 
In the same way I calculated $p_{81}=0.961, p_{82}=0.94.$

Next I wrote that $_2q_{80.5}=1-_2p_{80.5}=$

That's all I can get. I do not know how to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** You want the probability that a life aged $80.5$ survives to age $82.5$. Do you know how to compute the probability $_{0.5}p_{80.5}$ that a life aged $80.5$ survives to age $81$, and the probability $_{0.5}p_{82}$ that a life aged $82$ survives to age $82.5$? If so, multiplying the product of these by $p_{81}$ will get you the answer. In other words, we have $$\color{blue}{ _{2}p_{80.5} =\, _{0.5}p_{80.5}\times p_{81} \times\, _{0.5}p_{82}}.$$

Also remember that in UDD, for any $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $t\in [0,1]$, we have $_{t}p_{x}=1-tq_{x}$. You can use this to help calculate $_{0.5}p_{80.5}$ and $_{0.5}p_{82}$. Note that $_{0.5}p_{80.5} = \dfrac{p_{80}}{_{0.5}p_{80}}$.